# What are the meanings of these jokes: "Queers 'R' Us" and "I'm a proctologist so I drive a brown Probe."

Tags: meaning-in-context, jokes

In American TV show 'Office' Season 2 Episode 2, one man tells a joke:

> Well, those are some awful tight pants you have on. Where did you get 'em, like, Queers 'R' Us?

What's the funny point in this joke?

In Season 2 Episode 7, there is another joke:

> First guy: Well, I'm a astronaut, so I drive a Saturn.
>
> Second guy: Well, I am a pimp, so I drive a cheap Escort.
>
> Third guy: I got you both beat. I'm a proctologist so I drive a brown Probe.

What's the meaning of these two jokes?

Answer (score 7):

For the first joke, there are a few key ideas being referenced:

1. "Queers", in this case, is referring to homosexuals or gay men (i.e. men sexually/romantically attracted to other men).
2. Gay men stereotypically wear very tight pants.
3. The "'R' Us" part of "Queers 'R' Us" comes from the now discontinued toy store chain "Toys 'R' Us", and their sister store for infants "Babies 'R' Us".

With these three ideas in mind, there are two suggestions meant to be funny:

1. There is a store similar to "Toys 'R' Us" for gay men called "Queers 'R' Us" that presumably sells all sorts of supplies related to being gay, including tight pants. (This is funny because it's ridiculous, such a store obviously doesn't exist.)
2. The person wearing tight pants shops at that hypothetical store because they are a gay man. (While I don't personally find this sort of thing funny, it's common for men to call each other gay as a sort of humiliating joke.)

---

For the second joke, the key is understanding that each statement is a play on words that associates types of cars with professions. The professions being referenced are:

1. Astronauts - people who go into outer space
2. [Pimps - people who manage prostitutes (individuals who have sex for money)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procuring_(prostitution))
3. [Proctologists - doctors specializing in the health of your rectum, anus, and colon (where all of your poop is)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorectal_surgery)

The play on words with the cars is as follows:

1. An astronaut drives a Saturn because 'Saturn' is both a [type of car](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_Corporation) and the [name of a planet in our galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn).
2. A pimp drives an 'Escort' because that is both a [type of car](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_Escort_(North_America)) and another word for a prostitute. The joke is vulgar, suggesting that he both operates a cheap Escort vehicle and has sex with a prostitute who charges little money.
3. A proctologist drives a brown 'Probe' because it is both a [type of car](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_Probe) and references his job putting probes into people's butts ([a common procedure called an endoscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endoscopy) done to look for cancers), where there is brown poo.

Answer (score 2):

> 'Well, those are some awful tight pants you have on. Where did you get 'em, like, Queers 'R' Us?'

*The Office* is typical for crude and slightly cruel jokes. In this one, the joke is based on a stereotype about gay men. The stereotype is that if you are gay (a man attracted to another man) then you wear *very* tight pants, and that if you are a man wearing tight pants, you *surely* must be gay.

When the character asks where the tight pants come from, "Queers 'R' Us" is an allusion to "[Toys 'R' Us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toys_%22R%22_Us#21st_century)" which was extremely popular to kids toy store in the U.S. from the late 1990s through the early 2000s. **Queer** was historically a derogatory term for LGTB+ folks. The word has since been reclaimed by the LGBT+ community in some areas -- some folks like to use the word for themselves, so other's can't harm them with it, and take pride in the word as one to encompass all the community that is not an acronym. Other folks find the word has too much history and pain associated with it. Anyway, "Queers 'R' Us" is intended to be a sarcastic insult inside the joke. The joke, then, is one where the speaker of this joke is the one laughing, while the basis of his joke - gay men - bear the brunt of untrue stereotypes.

> First guy says, "Well, I'm a astronaut, so I drive a Saturn." And the second guy says, "Well, I am a pimp, so I drive a cheap Escort." And the third guy says, "I got you both beat. I'm a proctologist so I drive a brown Probe."

This joke is based on puns and allusions. The joke escalates with sexual humor with the second guy, and then crude and sexual humor with the third guy.

The first guy either actually *is* an astronaut, or is the owner of "[a Saturn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_Corporation)," which is a car brand. If the first guy is the owner of a Saturn [the car] then if he makes an allusion to Saturn [the planet] he could claim to be an astronaut -- who might in the distant future travel through space to land on that planet.

With the second guy, he claims he's "[a pimp](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/pimp?s=t)" which means he's someone who manages a "business" of selling people (usually for sex) to other people. "[escort](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/escort?s=t)" is a term that means a young (usually female) person who is hired as company for another person (either sexually or non-sexually, but often with the implication of the first, even if it doesn't happen). So, in this part, the pimp is claiming he "drives" "a cheap Escort". [An escort is also a type of vehicle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escort_vehicle), so there's the pun. But the rest of the "humor" comes from the idea of the pimp "driving" (as a euphemism for "riding" or "having sex with") "the escort".

Lastly, a "proctologist" is a person who's job is in "[proctology](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/proctology?s=t)" which "is the branch of medicine dealing with the rectum and anus. There is an instrument doctors use called "a probe," which is put into the rectum and anus to get samples, and check that the body is healthy. There is also a vehicle called [the Ford Probe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_Probe). So this last joke the third guy "drives a brown probe". The pun is that it *could* be a brown Ford Prove vehicle. But what this third guy refers to is actually "driving" (as in "inserting") the medical instrument "a probe" up another person's butt. And the medical probe is brown, because of poop. Theoretically, there is also the insinuation of anal sex, which is also called "gay sex" because gay men do it.